# Frenar un FOR si no encuentra un archivo JSON con FETCH - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, bucle-for, fetch

Estoy haciendo un sitio cuyo index carga notas almacenadas en JSON. El problema es que al no encontrar más notas, empieza a devolver ERROR 404. Quería saber si es posible indicarle al FETCH que si no encuentra el archivo, frene la iteración. Copio el código aquí debajo:

```
for( n=1 ; n <= 20 ; n++) {
fetch(`noticias/nota-${n}.json`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
            const caja = document.createElement("div");
            caja.setAttribute("class",`noti noti-${res.notaNumero}`);
            caja.setAttribute("id",res.notaNumero);
            noticias.appendChild(caja); 
                caja.innerHTML = 
                `<a href="noticia.html">
                    <div class="noti-img">
                        <img src="noticias/nota-${res.notaNumero}-cover.jpg" class="">
                        <h4 class="seccion-2">${res.seccion}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="noti-texto">
                        <h2 class="titulo-2">${res.titulo}</h2>
                        <h3 class="subtitulo-2">${res.subtitulo}</h3>
                    </div>
                </a>`;
        }).catch((e)=>{
            break;
        })
}
```

Comment: Para que el catch tome el error debes poner un throw. Esto es pon un consicional que si no es res.ok lance un throw

Comment: igual la idea es que si las notas estan todas dentro de un unico json hagas la peticion una sola vez y hagas luego un ciclo for in (para iterar sobre objetos) para leer los resultados de las notas

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es leer `nota-1.json` y si si existe, pintarla, y luego llamar a `nota-2.json` y si si existe, pintarla, luego llamar a `nota-3.json` y si no existe, detener y no preguntar por `nota-4.json` ni `nota-5.json`, etc., lo que debes hacer primero es esperar a que el `fetch` termine para revisar su resultado.
`fetch` es asíncrono, por lo tanto tus 20 solicitudes en este momento se realizan al tiempo.

Para ejecutarlas de forma secuencial y salir del ciclo debes hacer algo como:

```
for (n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
    let result = await fetch(`noticias/nota-${n}.json`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        break;
    }

    res = await res.json();
  
    const caja = document.createElement("div");
    caja.setAttribute("class", `noti noti-${res.notaNumero}`);
    caja.setAttribute("id", res.notaNumero);
    noticias.appendChild(caja);
    caja.innerHTML =
        `<a href="noticia.html">
            <div class="noti-img">
                <img src="noticias/nota-${res.notaNumero}-cover.jpg" class="">
                <h4 class="seccion-2">${res.seccion}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="noti-texto">
                <h2 class="titulo-2">${res.titulo}</h2>
                <h3 class="subtitulo-2">${res.subtitulo}</h3>
            </div>
        </a>`;
}
```

> Nota: Este código debes ejecutarlo dentro de una función asíncrona

Comment: Excelente! Voy a probar eso mismo! Gracias!!